# PHP SQL...query in an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a class and inside that class is this function which has a select statement in it

```
class homeclass {

    function viewHome(){
        $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","will","Idontknow!1");
        if (!$connection){
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        $db = mysql_select_db("willr", $connection);

        $query = "select id, text, image from home";
        $results = mysql_query($query, $connection);
        $results = mysql_fetch_array($results);

        return $results;

        $close = mysql_close($connection);
    }

}
```

I call that function in another file which is inside a case...like so

```
case"updatehome":
    $homeArray = $home->viewHome();
    print_r($homeArray);
    break;
```

When I do a print_r statment I get this back...

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [id] => 1 [1] => Test Header [text] => Test Header [2] => test.jpg [image] => test.jpg )
```

My question is why am I getting eveything twice? I dont understand

Comment: That's simple: becuse you don't read manual page for the function you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're using [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array), use [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc), which returns only associative array instead, or pass `MYSQL_ASSOC` as a second argument of `mysql_fetch_array`

Answer (score 1):

That class demonstrates poor knowledge of code. `return` ends the function block, so `mysql_close($connection);` is **never run**. Not to mention the overhead of opening a connection for every query... Just open the connection once at the start of your code, and all `mysql_query` calls from there assume that connection. Also, you define variables that are never used (`$db`, `$close`).

Anyway, `mysql_fetch_array` returns an array that contains both numeric keys (like in `mysql_fetch_rows`) and associative keys (like in `mysql_fetch_assoc`). Ideally, you should use `_rows` or `_assoc` depending on what's easier for the situation. Here, it's probably `_assoc` that you need.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting everything twice because [mysql_fetch_array](http://uk.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) returns the values in both 0-indexed format (the numeric indexes) and in associative format. If you want only one, either pass in the second parameter or use one of the other functions.

**BUT** before you go any further a few tips:

- List item
- investigate the PDO functions in MySQL. They will help you write better and more secure code.
- please don't post passwords and other sensitive info to SO.
- you might want to read up on OO design, or even investigate one of the many PHP frameworks out there. Even if you don't use one (and there are sometimes good reasons not to), trying one or two out can be a good way to start to get familiar with common OO Design patterns. Zend Framework, Symfony2 and CodeIgniter are 3 of the most popular (but by far not the only ones: [enter link description here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_frameworks#PHP))